# Using AuthorizationHandler to allow access based on another table/class

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-authorization

I need to limit access to those records in table `'Case'` for which a User is authorized. I have created a table `'CaseUser'`, that stores the userid's and `caseid`'s to resolve the n-m relation.

I have created a `ViewRequirement` class, added it to `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs` as a Singleton.

**Following I have created the following AuthorizationHandler:**

```
public class CaseViewHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ViewRequirement, Case>
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;       

        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ViewRequirement requirement, Case resource)
        {
            var caseUsers = from c in _context.CaseUser
                            .Where(t => t.CaseId == resource.CaseId || t.UserId == context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value)
                            select c;

            if(caseUsers != null)
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }     
    }
```

I am getting the Error

> Field 'CaseViewHandler._context' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

How can I inject the `CaseUser`class and use it in the `ViewHandler`?